# Значение слова наущивать

Tags: значение-слов, синонимы

Каково значение слова *наущивать*? В каком контексте оно употребляется? Какая разница между словом *наущивать* и словом *наущать*? Прочитал на одном сайте следующее:

''Синонимы слова «Наущать» (Наущивать, подговаривать, подстрекать) можно использовать в различных текстах, чтобы избежать однообразия и тавтологии в письменной речи. Возможно получится более логично выразить Вашу мысль, заменив слово «Наущать» на слова «Наущивать», «подговаривать», «подстрекать» в том или ином контексте. Каждый из синонимов слова «Наущать» имеет свое собственное значение. Чтобы не совершать банальных ошибок при употреблении синонимов слова «Наущать», таких как «Наущивать», «подговаривать», «подстрекать», нужно обратиться к толкованию этих слов и в итоге выбрать наиболее подходящее под ситуацию''.

И вот мне стало интересно. Нигде не могу найти ответ. Вбиваю в гугле, но гугл не выдаёт толкование слова *наущивать*. Объясните, пожалуйста, развёрнуто значение слова *наущивать* и в каком контексте его используют в отличие от синонима этого слова *наущать*.

Спасибо, что проявили терпение и прочитали  мой вопрос. ) А также спасибо за ответ. )

Answer (score 2):

Разница между *наущивать* и *наущать* стилистическая (но не смысловая): первое - просторечие, что выпадает из рамок нормативной лексики, второе - нейтральное, хоть и имеет помету "устар.".

[НАУЩАТЬ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/192704)

> Подстрекать, подговаривать к нападению на кого-либо или к каким-либо враждебным
>   действиям по отношению к кому-либо.

[Этимология по Фасмеру](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C):

> Образовано от на-/под- + уста́; ср. внуши́ть. Происходит от др.-русск.
>   наустити (πείθειν), ст.-слав. наустъ «способный» (ἱκανός), наустьникъ
>   – то же (Срезн. II, 345). Сюда же расширение из наусти́ть –
>   нау́ськать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот великий Даль ошибается, сочтя *наущение* и *науку* однокоренными. *Наука* происходит [от слав. *na- + *učiti](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0), восходящего к [др.-русск. укъ «учение», учити.](https://vasmer.lexicography.online/%D0%BD/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Я не уверен насчёт Москвы, но в Питере говорят не "наущивать", а "науськивать". (Хотя при этом говорят "по наущению".)